# In CNN with caffe, Can I set up initial caffemodel?

Tags: gpu, restart, convolution, caffe

I have operated CNN using caffe.
however, system was forced termination.
I have caffemodel so far.

Can I restart learning from now on using current caffemodel?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caffe supports resuming as explained [here](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/imagenet.html#resume-training):

> We all experience times when the power goes out [...] Since we are snapshotting intermediate results during training, we will be able to resume from snapshots.

This is available via the `--snapshot` option of the main caffe command-line tool, e.g:

```
./build/tools/caffe train [...] --snapshot=caffenet_train_10000.solverstate
```

As explained within the doc `caffenet_train_10000.solverstate` is:

> the solver state snapshot that stores all necessary information to recover the exact solver state.

In particular you can find more precisions about how to configure snapshotting from the [solver documentation](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/solver.html#snapshotting-and-resuming).